# Why @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW) does not commit?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, transactions, java-ee-7

I have `OwnerService` class which contain this code:

```
public RegisterOwnerResult registerOwner(RegisterOwnerRequest request) {
    try {
        Owner owner = doRegisterOwner(request);
        return RegisterOwnerResult.createSuccessful(owner.getId());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return RegisterOwnerResult.createUnsuccessful();
    }
}

@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
private Owner doRegisterOwner(RegisterOwnerRequest request) {
    Account account = new Account(request.getEmail(), request.getPassword());
    Owner owner = new Owner(account, request.getFirstName(), request.getLastName());

    ownerFacade.create(owner);

    return owner;
}
```

and Startup Singleton bean which should initiate the database:

```
@PostConstruct
public void initiate() {
    RegisterOwnerRequest registerOwnerRequest = new RegisterOwnerRequest(
            "john.barton@example.com",
            "pass123",
            "John",
            "Barton"
    );
    RegisterOwnerResult registerOwnerResult = ownerService.registerOwner(registerOwnerRequest);
    if (registerOwnerResult.wasSuccessful()) {
        System.out.println("Owner ID: " + registerOwnerResult.getOwnerId());
    }
}
```

but unfortunately registerOwnerResult.getOwnerId() returns null. I suppose that the reason is that method `doRegisterOwner` doesn't commit changes to database. I don't know if it is feature or a bug but nonetheless I'd like to make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design.  Only external calls (i.e., calls from other beans that go through the container's proxy/interception system) respect any of the attributes.

If you want calls to `doRegisterOwner` be in a new transaction, move that code to another session bean.  Or simply move the annotation to the public `registerOwner` method in `OwnerService`.

Comment: Do you think it is better to create another session bean or commit transaction by hand?

Comment: See me edit, which should suffice in your example.  In general, container managed transaction are completely fine for most situations, one barely needs user managed transactions.

Comment: But when I move the annotation to the public `registerOwner` method `ownerId` field still be null.